# the time complexity of Skip List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, skip-lists

May I know why the time complexity of insertion of skip list is O(log n) for average case, and why the height of Skip list with n elements is O(log n) in high probability. And why average search time in each layer is O(1).

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help with the O(log n) part.

Basically...
 [[Skip list searching] is quite reminiscent of binary search in an array and is perhaps the best way to intuitively understand why the maximum number of nodes visited in this list is in .](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/341/fall01/Lectures/SkipLists/skip_lists/skip_lists.html)